# Remote desktop protocol to display 3D game

Tags: remote-desktop, 3d-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to run games over remote desktop?](https://superuser.com/questions/209023/is-it-possible-to-run-games-over-remote-desktop)

OS: WinXP

I was wondering if Windows built-in RDP or 3rd party solution, like [RemoteCall](http://www.remotecall.net/), can also display 3D game play (running on remote host) through RDP and display on my local host? Or is there any other solution can make this possible? My guess is VNC protocol probably can do, but it will be very slow, since the frame rate highly depends on BW.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but the screen is going to be very choppy in live action games or FPS's. You can play turn based games like Civ quite well though. See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/209023/is-it-possible-to-run-games-over-remote-desktop/209030#209030) post for more details particularly the accepted answer about On-live. I want to add more to this but all the info you need is in the other post, actually this should probably be flagged as a dupe.