# How can I stream a game running on one computer to play on another?

Tags: remote-desktop

I've seen this topic:

[Is it possible to run games over remote desktop?](https://superuser.com/questions/209023/is-it-possible-to-run-games-over-remote-desktop)

and a few more, but almost all topics about that are pretty old, processors & graphics cards are now faster, and there are new improved technologies in video encoding etc.

If I buy a very fast desktop instead of an expensive laptop, and use my old awesome indestructible IBM laptop to connect to it, what technology/settings should I be using?

Obviously with an emphasis on gaming, so something that supports high Frame Rates and low input lag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully, that "very fast desktop" is a server with [VMWare Horizon View](http://www.vmware.com/products/horizon-view) installed on it. You can then create a virtualized desktop that your "IBM laptop" connects to via RDP or PC-over-IP (PCoIP). PCoIP will give you the higher frame rates so that is recommended over RDP. Here's a [neat comparison between PCoIP and RDP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MifH_Jp8aK0).